# symbolic link to a large file

Tags: linux, centos

I have a large(1 TB) file that I would like to download from the centos server via http, should I create a symbolic link to the file to the http file directory?  would the link work?  the file is too large to be copied over given the server hdd.
if not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you have the [Options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options) `FollowSymLinks` enabled for that `Directory` or `Location` (or in an `.htaccess` file, if they are enabled for that `Directory` or `Location`).

Just test on another, smaller symlinked file to be sure it's enabled before trying with the full file, if you have concerns.

Answer (score 1):

See mount --bind.  From the mount man page:

```
The bind mounts.
          Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount  part  of  the  file
          hierarchy somewhere else. The call is
                 mount --bind olddir newdir
          or shortoption
                 mount -B olddir newdir
          or fstab entry is:
                 /olddir /newdir none bind

          After  this  call the same contents is accessible in two places.
          One can also remount a single file (on a single file).

          This call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not  pos‐
          sible  submounts.  The entire file hierarchy including submounts
          is attached a second place using
                 mount --rbind olddir newdir
          or shortoption
                 mount -R olddir newdir
```